# AJAX: Replace a div's content with a specific div from the collected data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

To me that looks correct, but i'm not experienced with AJAX in the slightest, been stuck at it for hours trying many variations including filter and it's all been useless. This is currently what i have and i can't see anything wrong with it.

What is happening is that no chat messages are showing up like they usually do, if i was to just refresh the page.

What i am simply trying to accomplish is a chat interface if that has any relevance.

Here is a live example of what is happening: http://www.mixpix.eu/chat/chat.php?r=G97NxXy4exbLQPFU

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() { 
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "html",
                    url: 'chat.php?r=' + <?php echo "'" .$_GET['r']. "'"; ?> , 
                    success: function(data) {
                        var trim = $(data).find('.message_window');
                        $('.message_window').replaceWith(trim);
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);
});
```

Here's the contents of my body tag:

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class"inbox_window" id="style-3">

        </div>
        <div class="message_window" id="style-3">
            <table width="100%">
                <p class="talking_to"><?php echo getFirstnamebyID($_GET['r']); ?></p>
                <?php echo displayMessages(); ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <form class="submit_form" method="post" <?php echo 'action="chat.php?r='.$_GET['r'].'"' ?>>
            <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type message here" />
            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="s_say"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

displayMessages() function in php:

```
function displayMessages() {
    $user_id = getUserID();
    $sql = mysql_query(strip_tags("SELECT * FROM inbox WHERE (send_id='".$user_id."' OR send_id='".$_GET['r']."') AND (rec_id='".$_GET['r']."' OR rec_id='".$user_id."') ORDER BY timestamp;"));
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            if ($row['send_id'] == $user_id) {
                echo '<tr><td><p class="sm">'. $row['messages'] .'</p></td></tr>';
            } else if ($row['send_id'] == $_GET['r']) {
                echo '<tr><td><p class="rm">'. $row['messages'] .'</p></td></tr>';
            } else {
                echo "Unable to display messages.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Be the first to say hello!";
    }
}
```

I would be highly thankful for any ones help as it's driving me a bit insane.

Comment: Can you post the php code in chat.php?  It appears your ajax method is returning a DOM element, which seems strange to me.

Comment: It's the same page. I'm trying to accomplish it all in the one chat.php. I shall post what function im attempting to redraw, which is displayMessages().

Comment: Maybe just `.append();` new messages instead of `.replaceWith();`?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few things happening here that are going to cause you problems...

On the JavaScript side, `setInterval` is a hacky way to keep your content current, this could better be achieved with sockets. If you really want to do it this way, returning the whole document (including the HTML `head`) is not your best option -- maybe send an extra query param that tells your PHP to only send the messages section, or better yet, the messages that have been added since the timestamp you last checked.

In your markup, you can't put a paragraph tag directly inside your table, or raw text, as can come back from your PHP. You're not really using it as a table anyway, a list would probably be more semantic.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I will look into sockets, but first I shall rewrite what I have here as simplistic as possible! I just want to wrap head around it as i'll be using it in all pages of my site. Thank you!